# XML Parsing using LINQ to fetch attribute along with contents

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Here is my XML,

```
<content id = "C1">
<paragraph >
      <Info />
      <contentValue>Content1</contentValue>
</paragraph>

<paragraph>
      <Info />
      <contentValue>Content2</contentValue>
</paragraph>
<content>

<content id = "C2">
<paragraph >
      <Info />
      <contentValue>Content3</contentValue>
</paragraph>

<paragraph>
      <Info />
      <contentValue>Content4</contentValue>
</paragraph>

<paragraph>
      <Info />
      <contentValue>Content5</contentValue>
</paragraph>
<content>
```

I need to parse through each of `<content>` tags and fetch the values of `<contentvalue>` tags and store it in a List.

I'm using following code but, values of `<contentvalue>` tags are concatinated like '**Content1Content2**'

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path);
var Contents = xdoc.Descendants("content").Select(c => (string)c).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things I noticed:

1. Your XML is not in a correct format
2. You are trying to select Content node and render it as string, which is wrong

### XML:

```
<root>
    <content id="C1">
        <paragraph>
            <Info/>
            <contentValue>Content1</contentValue>
        </paragraph>
        <paragraph>
            <Info/>
            <contentValue>Content2</contentValue>
        </paragraph>
    </content>
    <content id="C2">
        <paragraph>
            <Info/>
            <contentValue>Content3</contentValue>
        </paragraph>
        <paragraph>
            <Info/>
            <contentValue>Content4</contentValue>
        </paragraph>
        <paragraph>
            <Info/>
            <contentValue>Content5</contentValue>
        </paragraph>
    </content>
</root>
```

### Code:

```
var Contents = xdoc.Descendants("content").Descendants("paragraph").Select(i => i.Element("contentValue").Value).ToList();
```

Above code exactly selects `contentValue` node under `paragraph`.

Comment: Siva Charan - Also require the contentID along with the values.

Comment: @Raghavendra: In that case, what is the expected output on the list

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want your `<contentValue>`s to be grouped by the `<content>` tag, just try:

**V1**

```
var Contents = xdoc.Descendants("contentValue").Select(c => (string)c).ToArray();
```

or
**V2**

```
var Contents = xdoc.Root.XPathSelectElements("content/paragraph/contentValue")
       .Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

**NOTE** that for using the **V2** solution you need to add a reference to the `System.Xml.XPath` namespace.

---

(This next section represents **a different solution, for a different but similar case**, provided for reference purposes)
Otherwise, if you need to get the values grouped by the `<content>` tag, you could try:

```
var grouped = xdoc.Descendants("contentValue")
       .Select(x => new { PNode = x.Ancestors("content")
       .FirstOrDefault().Attribute("id").Value, CNode = x.Value })
       .GroupBy(x => x.PNode).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());
```

This then can be iterated as follows:

```
foreach (var group in grouped)
{
     Console.WriteLine("content id = " + group.Key);
     foreach (var singleCValue in group.Value)
     {
          Console.WriteLine(singleCValue.CNode);
     }
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing this in such a complex way. Refer my **[answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20187217/500725)**

Comment: @SivaCharan, please read my post carefully. The solution to the question is the very first line of code. It iterated the `descendants` of the node only once, which is not complex at all. You iterate them twice. I start my post stating that the solution to come is for the case in which @Raghavendra does not need the values grouped by the `<content>` node. The second part of my answer provides a solution for grouping the `<contentValue>` node values by the corresponding `<content>` node. Therefore I'm providing two solutions, for two very distinct situations, as the OP did not specify the case.

Comment: Your first line of code itself wrong. It will fail, if there is a  `contentValue` node outside `paragraph` node. Please have a understanding of how `xdoc.Descendants("contentValue")` works.

Comment: @SivaCharan, please be respectful. I did not insult you, and I used an appropriate tone. My answer is in the context of the provided XML.

Comment: My friend I'm helping you in understand the concept. So I don't have any intention to hurt you :). Sorry if I have make you to feel bad.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your tags are not well formed. You can do something like this.

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);

            IList<string> list=new List<string>();

            IEnumerable<XElement> contentElements = doc.Descendants("content");//this get all "content" tags
            IEnumerable<XElement> contentValueElements = contentElements.Descendants("contentValue");//this get all "contentValue" tags

            foreach (XElement i in contentValueElements)
            {

                    list.Add(i.Value);
            }
```